# What is the best way to get at nested dictionaries from a third party plist?

Tags: ios, plist, nsdictionary

I have a IOS plist generated by a third party's app I am trying to interface to, consequently I cannot modify the format of the plist.  The part that is giving me trouble is an array of Dictionaries, the cardList array.  I have loaded the plist into a NSMutableDictionary with no problem and can 'dump' the cardList and colorLabelList arrays.

First Question:  What is the best way to access each member of the Item array's? i.e., draft, label, etc. for each of the cards in the list.

2nd Question:  Is my 'loading into a NSMutableDictionary' approach the best choice?

Here is the layout of the plist:

```
cardlist   Array
  item 0   Dictionary
     draft   boolean
     label   string
     notes   string
     ...
  item 1   Dictionary
     draft
     label
     notes
     ...
name       string
sortOrder  number
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NSMutableDictionary only if you are actually going to change the data, otherwise use a standard NSDictionary (this is more of style thing, the actual implementation does not really change).

If you want to cycle through the cardlist array, do the following:

```
//This will enumerate through the array element by element
for (NSMutableDictionary *dictionary in cardlist) {
   //Ok, now we have a dictionary from cardlist
   //Let's print the items to the console
   NSLog(@"draft: %i", [dictionary valueForKey:@"draft"]); //Note, there are better ways print print a bool to the log, but this will work for now
   NSLog(@"label: %@", [dictionary valueForKey:@"label"]);
   NSLog(@"notes: %@", [dictionary valueForKey:@"notes"]);

}
```

That should go through all of your cardlist array and print the values.

Comment: Thank you, and I understand about the NSMutableDictionary part. Naturally there is a Master-Detail thing that will be happening after this, with the Title being the Master and the rest of the record being the detail.

Maybe I'd be better off just loading the record into defined class. 

Is this the fastest way to cycle through the list?  And again, thanx so much.

Comment: No problem. If the answer helped then please accept it by clicking the check mark next to the question. To learn more about enumerating collections you should have a look at the docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Enumerators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000135-BBCFABCB